# JavaScript function in PHP page causing issues with PHP tabs format

Tags: javascript, php, formatting, sorttable.js

I am trying to reference a JavaScript file, containing a table sort function, in a PHP file.
Everything functions the way it should, but once I add the code below to my PHP report page it causes issues with the format of the tabs on my navigation page. The same issue comes up if I add a random `document.write` outside of the PHP code. Not a huge issue but rather unsightly to the user.

Is there a better way to reference the JavaScript source doc that will not interfer with my php navigation page format? I feel like there is a simple fix that I am not grasping.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="include/sorttable.js"></script>
```

Also used an the PHP `echo` inside the PHP tags to make the call, same issue.

Here is part of the navigation code for the tabs that the format issue is coming up on.

```
<?php

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function start_page_printer_friendly(
      $section = "home",
      $headContents = null,
      $bodyAttributes = null
)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

{?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title><?php print $page_title; ?></title>
<link href="/trellis_portal/include/portal.css" media="screen"
   rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <?php if ( ! is_null($headContents)) { print $headContents; } ?>
   </head>

<body onload="printpage();" <?php if ( ! is_null($bodyAttributes)) { print $bodyAttributes; } ?>>
   <script language="JavaScript">
      <!--
         function printpage() { window.print(); }
      -->
   </script>
<br />
<?php                     
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function start_page( $section = "home",
                     $subsection = null,
                     $headContents = null,
                     $bodyAttributes = null
                   )
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{   
    if (isset($_GET['printer']))
    {
        start_page_printer_friendly();
        return;
    }
   $section = strtolower($section);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title><?php print $page_title; ?></title>

 <?php if ( ! is_null($headContents)) { print $headContents; } ?>
   </head>

<body class=" yui-skin-sam" <?php if ( ! is_null($bodyAttributes)) { print $bodyAttributes; } ?>>
<br />


<div id="header">
<ul>
<!-- 
   <li><a class="<?php print tabSelector($section, 'executive'); ?>"
      href="/trellis_portal/portal.php?section=executive&title=Executive">Executive</a></li>
   <li><a
      class="<?php print tabSelector($section, 'community'); ?>"
      href="/trellis_portal/portal.php?section=community&title=Community">Community</a></li>
-->   
   <li><a class="<?php print tabSelector($section, 'trellis'); ?>"
      href="/trellis_portal/portal.php?section=trellis&title=Trellis">Trellis</a></li>
<!--
```

Comment: Would be easier if you show the code.

Comment: Explain "PHP navigation page format"

Comment: each section has a subsection which has mutiple reports, these reports have use a report class file for that formats and contains all the user functions this report class is where the javascript source reference is at.

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML code. We can't guess what your PHP code is going to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't get what you expect but one thing I can see already: EVERYTHING outside  is literally transposed, thus

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE...
```

will introduce an extra whitespace (newline) at the start before DOCTYPE.

Also the ending of the script ( --> ) will generate JS syntax error. It is valid HTML but must be commented out ( //--> ) in JS.

Comment: thanks a bunch your post pushed me in the right direction. Location, Location, Location

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the situation yet, but you need to be aware that there is nothing PHP related on your page, *only HTML/CSS/Javascript code that happened to be generated by PHP*. So you need to look into your HTML code and see what the problem is there. You may then want to update your question with actual HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

*SCRIPT* tags, in themselves, cannot affect elements or layout within the page.

Your problem is likely elsewhere. To debug this I would ignore the PHP and focus on the HTML output and look for unclosed tags and invalid markup etc.